# Can't create new VM instance in GCP

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have been getting the error ***"Quota 'IN_USE_ADDRESSES' exceeded. Limit: 23.0"*** suddenly, when I try to create a new vm instance from GCP console.

About 20 vm instances have been running in my account, but currently I can NOT create a new vm instance both from exist images and my snapshots.

Does anyone know how can I fix the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've hit the default limit for "external in-use IP addresses".

Using Developers Console, go to your project, then Compute-> Compute Engine-> Quotas, on the top of the page click on "Change request". Fill out the form and apply for "Total requested number of external in-use IP addresses" for the region which reached to the limit. The default limit is 23.

Comment: does this cost more money to do?